# Can I set up a website to retrieve data from my own back-end server

Tags: web-hosting

I've made a website for an arts organisation. The website allows people to browse a database of artists' work. The database is large and the image files for the artists' work come to about 150Gb. I have my own server that is currently just being used to keep the images on its hard-drive.

I'm going to purchase hosting so I don't have to worry about bandwidth etc... but would it be better to purchase hosting that allows me to upload my entire image database or should I use the website to get the images from my server? If so how would I do that?

Sorry I am very new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be better to have the data on the same server so you avoid calls to another server for images which are quite big as you say and this can slow you down overall.

I assume you will need to set up some API on your server to deliver the images or at least URLs for them but then you must make sure they are accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want the image files on the same server as your website, as requests elsewhere to pull in images will definitely hinder your site's performance - especially if you have large files.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at large size of database and consideration of bandwidth, dedicated server will be suitable as they includes large disk spaces and bandwidth. You can install webserver as well as database server on same server inspite of managing them separately. Managing database backups and service monitoring becomes much more easier.

For an instance, you can review dedicated server configuration and resources here :- https://www.accuwebhosting.com/dedicated-servers